# Use Vuejs variable in Validations

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I try to do a simple maxValue, but I am not sure how can I use a value from vue data. [URL](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-builtin-validators) for package.

```
import { required, maxValue } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      totalClauses: 10,
    };
  },
  validations: {
    nr_of_clauses: {
      required,
      maxValue: maxValue(this.totalClauses)
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't belong.  Is nothing fancy here, just a variable from vuejs "totalClauses" that I want to use in validations (I will edit the post with package URL). Right now I get error when I try to use it in maxValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Validations schema can be a function, which will make it dynamic and possibly dependant on your model's data. <sup>[[source]](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-dynamic-validation-schema)</sup>

So,

```js
import { required, maxValue } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      totalClauses: 10,
    };
  },

  validations() {
    return {
      nr_of_clauses: {
        required,
        maxValue: maxValue(this.totalClauses)
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the answer for this issue was found, but i want to quickly recommend changing from **Vuelidate** to **VeeValidate**. I've used both and Vuelidate has some limitations that VeeValidate solves like custom validations(with messages for each validation) and it's more simple to use.

You can find Veevalidate documentation [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/)

Comment: Cool, I heard about it, but I didn't tried. With first opportunity I will try it.